# call DLL library method/function from Java code

Tags: java, dll

I need to call the methods that can be reached in the dll but I can not access them, here is the dll

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

    public interface simpleDLL extends Library {
        simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary("HComPinpad", simpleDLL.class);
        void DllUnregisterServer();  
        String ReadCard();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         simpleDLL sdll = simpleDLL.INSTANCE;
         sdll.ReadCard();
    }    
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'ReadCard': No se encontró el proceso especificado.

Here is the DLL information:

[image: DLL information]

Comment: here dll  https://www.dropbox.com/s/yto0tpui0zecexp/HComPinpad.dll?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about the communication between Java and .dll files, but shortly I also had to call some dll functions and I have been advised to use [com4j](https://github.com/kohsuke/com4j), because its just easy to use. I really don't know why your example is not working, but you might wonna have a look at com4j as well.

This way you can avoid annoying typos and be sure, you get all methods supported from that specific .dll.

There is a [com4j tutorial](https://com4j.java.net/tutorial.html), which describes how to use com4j with .ocx files, but it workes same way for .dll files as well.